# Caddy file download

Tags: php, caddy

I'm freaking out with caddy. I have a PHP code that downloads a zip file. It's works flawlessly with Apache, however, with Caddy I'm unable to download the zip. Instead, the file is displayed in the browser.

I was reading Caddy docs about mime types but it did not solve my problem.

Is anybody able to download a file instead of opening it in the browser using Caddy?

Edit:

PHP code:

```
     header("Pragma: public");
     header("Expires: 0");
     header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
     header("Cache-Control: public");
     header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
     header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
     header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath));
     while (ob_get_level()) {
         ob_end_clean();
     }
     @readfile($filepath);

     return;
```

Caddyfile:

```
mywebsite.com
{
    root * /website
    encode gzip
    php_fastcgi php:9000
    file_server
    rewrite /admin/* /admin/index.php?{query}
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code you're using to download the file.

Comment: I just edited @Triby

Comment: I can think of 2 possibilities here: 1: There's a bug in Caddy 2: Maybe there is a previous content sent to browser before that has already sent headers.

Comment: Does it work in Caddy 1?

Comment: Please include precise & complete instructions to reproduce the behavior you're seeing.